# Open source for exploring drive

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a vba code in which the user need to provide the path to a file. I know that the client will need to work with many files and typing the path is not efficient and might introduce errors. I would like to know if someone knows where i can find a vba code that will open a window (panel or whateever) in which the user can point to the correct file (like when we do open file in 90% of applications)
thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can;

```
Dim file As String
With Application.FileDialog(3)
    .InitialFileName = "c:\xxx\"
    .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt", 1
    .Show
    If (.SelectedItems.Count) Then
        file = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

MsgBox file
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. One last thing, the files i am supposed to work with often are excel files (.xls or .xlsx). I simply need to add the accepted extentions using the filters.Add function right?

Comment: Yes, that's all you need to do.

Comment: One last thing if possible, an error pops up when i hit the cancel button. In my vba code i set an if condition that checks if file is null. Nevertheless, the "error 1004 sorry we couldn't find. It is possible that it was renamed, moved, or deleted" . Is there a way to cancel the execution of the code without an error popping?